# Formatting date with leading zeros for month and day and removing slashes

Tags: python, datetime

The incoming date looking like this:

```
3/9/2015
```

I have figured out how to strip the `/` marks out of the date so I now have this:

```
392015
```

Now, I need to have the leading zeros in the month and day, so the desired output is

```
03092015
```

Answer (score 3):

Split and then fill and join:

```
newDate = ''.join(i.zfill(2) for i in oldDate.split('/'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of stripping out the slashes, split it by them. You'll have 3 different numbers in a list, relating to day, month, and year, so go through each of them, and if the length is 1, add a zero to the start. Finally join these together and you have your number.

There's also another quick way to add leading zeroes. Using `str().zfill( num )` will pad out the string with zeroes until it's a certain number of characters.

Since you should be able to write it yourself following the first paragraph, I'll put in a one line version so you can see that it works, but not copy it since it'll be obvious you didn't write it.

```
i = "3/9/2015"

print ''.join(x.zfill(2) for x in i.split('/'))
# 03092015
```

This is a way without zfill:

```
print ''.join(('0' if len(x)<2 else '')+x for x in i.split('/'))
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did.

Comment: Yeah looks like it haha, I was in the middle of writing though so didn't see yours ;p

Comment: Would this work if I get dates like 12/1/1996 and 12/12/1996 as well?  Would this know that the months and days should always be 2 digits?

Comment: Yeah, the number given in `zfill` means it'll only add zeros until the string hits that length, which in this case is 2 :)

Comment: We are using python 2.5 and we get errors when using this code.  Do you know a different code for version 2.5 to accomplish this?

Comment: Nope, but I can take a guess it's probably zfill, I did a bit at the bottom without it, although you should ideally be doing it yourself haha.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use for-loops or anything too fancy just do something simple like this:

```
date = '392015'

newdate = '0' + date[0] + '0' + date[1:]
```

This will output:

```
03092015
```

Literally, all this is doing is 'adding' zeros.

**Update**: For this *primitive* technique to work on all dates, just use two *primitive* 'if-statements' ;)

```
date = '3/9/2015'
oldDate = date.split('/')

if len(oldDate[0]) < 2:
    oldDate[0]= '0' + oldDate[0]
if len(oldDate[1]) < 2:
    oldDate[1]= '0' + oldDate[1]

newDate = ''.join(oldDate)
```

(Note: I'm just giving the OP OPtions, by no means am I claiming this is a superior method)

Comment: That's such a primitive technique.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi I know, but I didn't wanna get reprimanded for copying you ;)